# set http header in perl to force download the content

Tags: perl, header, http-headers

I am trying to force download a file by sending http headers via perl. the current code is as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Session;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

use HTTP::Headers;

HTTP::Headers->new(
                Content_type =>  'text/plain',
                Content_disposition => 'attachment; filename=export.txt',
            );
print 'just some text';
exit;
```

I have also included `HTTP::Headers` however when I run this, it prints out the text instead of downloading the content...

Comment: Show us more code, are you using CGI, or another Web framework?

Comment: I am using CGI, I have added more code

Comment: Are you using CGI.pm, or manually constructing CGI responses?

Comment: @SlavenRezic I am using CGI.pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using CGI, you can set it when printing the header via CGI that way:

```
my $q = CGI->new();
print $q->header(
  -type    => 'text/plain',
  -charset => 'iso-8859-1',
  -attachment => 'filename.txt',

);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're just constructing the `HTTP::Headers`, but it's never printed to stdout. So you have to call also the `as_string` method:

```
my $h = HTTP::Headers->new(
                           Content_type =>  'text/plain',
                           Content_disposition => 'attachment; filename=export.txt',
                          );
print $h->as_string;
```

But this is just printing the HTTP header without the separator between header and body. If you want to let libwww-perl to do this for you, you can also use `HTTP::Message`:

```
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTTP::Message;

my $h = HTTP::Headers->new(
                           Content_type =>  'text/plain',
                           Content_disposition => 'attachment; filename=export.txt',
                          );
my $content = 'just some text';
my $msg = HTTP::Message->new($h, $content);
print $msg->as_string;
```

To be more correct, you should probably use "\r\n" as line terminators:

```
print $msg->as_string("\015\012");
```

Another alternative is to use `CGI.pm`, and use the `header` method, which can be used to set response HTTP headers. Actually, using `CGI.pm` is more common than using the `HTTP::*` classes. The latter are more common in use when dealing with dealing with `LWP::UserAgent` to *fetch* web pages.

Answer (score 1):

ok I figured out a simpler way...

instead of using `HTTP::Headers` I simply printed out the following lines:

```
print"Content-type:text/plain\n";
print"Content-disposition:attachment; filename=export.txt\n\n";
```

which did the trick...

Comment: I prefer using a Modul for that. Why? because when something changed, the module need to be changed, not the whole scripts. The point is just the maintainability for that kind of uses :)

Comment: `Content-type: text/plain` for text files, `application/octet-stream` for generic binary stream. Any other [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) if you know the type in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code using the CGI module:

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
print header(-type => "text/plain", -content_disposition => "attachment; filename=filename=export.txt");            
print "just some text";
```